# How can I strip out properties from a CSS file that don't relate to color with regex?

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio-code

I find myself with a CSS file where I need to strip out all properties that don't relate to color but maintain any custom classes, ids, and standard HTML elements. I initially tried to do this by combining a reverse regex selection in vscode with an entire line selection based on the beginning string, but I'm terrible at regex.

This `^.((?!(color|background-color)).)*$` was as far as I was able to progress, which does eliminate the lines that don't begin with color or background-color from the selection. However, I couldn't determine how to address classes (.), ids(#), and regular HTML elements.

Or, if there is a simpler solution to the problem, please advise.

Thanks, in advance.

Example:

```
    p {
      line-height: 1.5;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }

    .my-class {
      line-height: 1.5;
      width: 20%;
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }

    #my-id {
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin: auto;
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }
```

Should resolve to below with the non-color properties removed

```
    p {
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }

    .my-class {
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }

    #my-id {
      color: #f4f4f4;
      background-color: #444;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assuming the file is more or less formatted,
instead of advanced parsing, we can just filter the lines and remove those with `:` that don't contain the word `color` *and* has ';' in them.

EDIT:
This might still not be enough, because different files might be formatted differently. I have a better algorithm by checking only the parts between `{` and `}` and then splitting by `;` and then checking each part for existence of word `color`...

But for now this might be good enough? For best results, format the css file. Size of css shouldn't be a limit.

```js
var css = `p,
.another,
#id_new_line {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #444;
}

.my-class,
.my-class::after {
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 20%;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #444;
}

#my-id {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: auto;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #444;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}`;

var arr_colors = ["aliceblue", "antiquewhite", "aqua", "aquamarine", "azure", "beige", "bisque", "black", "blanchedalmond", "blue", "blueviolet", "brown", "burlywood", "cadetblue", "chartreuse", "chocolate", "coral", "cornflowerblue", "cornsilk", "crimson", "cyan", "darkblue", "darkcyan", "darkgoldenrod", "darkgray", "darkgrey", "darkgreen", "darkkhaki", "darkmagenta", "darkolivegreen", "darkorange", "darkorchid", "darkred", "darksalmon", "darkseagreen", "darkslateblue", "darkslategray", "darkslategrey", "darkturquoise", "darkviolet", "deeppink", "deepskyblue", "dimgray", "dimgrey", "dodgerblue", "firebrick", "floralwhite", "forestgreen", "fuchsia", "gainsboro", "ghostwhite", "gold", "goldenrod", "gray", "grey", "green", "greenyellow", "honeydew", "hotpink", "indianred", "indigo", "ivory", "khaki", "lavender", "lavenderblush", "lawngreen", "lemonchiffon", "lightblue", "lightcoral", "lightcyan", "lightgoldenrodyellow", "lightgray", "lightgrey", "lightgreen", "lightpink", "lightsalmon", "lightseagreen", "lightskyblue", "lightslategray", "lightslategrey", "lightsteelblue", "lightyellow", "lime", "limegreen", "linen", "magenta", "maroon", "mediumaquamarine", "mediumblue", "mediumorchid", "mediumpurple", "mediumseagreen", "mediumslateblue", "mediumspringgreen", "mediumturquoise", "mediumvioletred", "midnightblue", "mintcream", "mistyrose", "moccasin", "navajowhite", "navy", "oldlace", "olive", "olivedrab", "orange", "orangered", "orchid", "palegoldenrod", "palegreen", "paleturquoise", "palevioletred", "papayawhip", "peachpuff", "peru", "pink", "plum", "powderblue", "purple", "rebeccapurple", "red", "rosybrown", "royalblue", "saddlebrown", "salmon", "sandybrown", "seagreen", "seashell", "sienna", "silver", "skyblue", "slateblue", "slategray", "slategrey", "snow", "springgreen", "steelblue", "tan", "teal", "thistle", "tomato", "turquoise", "violet", "wheat", "white", "whitesmoke", "yellow", "yellowgreen"];

var arr = css.split("\n").filter(function(line) {
  var parts = line.split(":");
  if (parts.length > 1) {

    var value = parts[1].toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_colors.length; i++) {
      var color = arr_colors[i];
      if (value.indexOf(color) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (value.indexOf('#') > -1 || value.indexOf("rgb") > -1 || value.indexOf("hsl") > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if (line.indexOf(':') > -1) {
    return false
  }

  return true;

});
var new_css = arr.join("\n")
console.log(new_css)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that method would be practical as the CSS file is 30k lines long. Would it?

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so that it picks up hex codes, rgb codes, and rgba codes rather than just 'color'? There are numerous properties that are using these color codes aside from just that. That was a bad example on my part in my op. I suppose regex would be necessary as there are numerous colors, but I need to be able to filter them. If you need a reference for those codes see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Applying_color) and/or below. 

Hex Code: `#00000`, RGB Code: `rgb(000,000,000)`, RGBA Code: `rgba(000,000,00,0.0)`
```

Comment: Ok, whenever I add the actual css in between the ticks, it either outright fails or gives a `Invalid escape sequence in template` error, depending on where I'm testing it. For the sake of expediency, I've created a project on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-hill-2g0k62?file=/src/index.js). I really suck at javascript.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying some character is not escaped properly in the css string. Try elimination to find the line 2329 which is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZVXad/1)

Find: `(^\s*(color|background-color).*$)|(^\s*.*\{$)|(^\s*\}$)|^\s*.*$\n`

It is just a big alternation, order is important - the lines you don't want should be last so that more specific groups with `{` or `}` or the color properties are matched first.

Note that the last group also includes the trailing `\n` so that the line is removed in the replace.

Replace: `$1$3$4`

Comment: This expression does not work in vscode. Error below:
`Invalid expression: (^\s*(color|background-color).*$)|(^\s*.*{$)|(^\s*}$)|^\s*.*$\n: Lone quantifier brackets`

Comment: @Forceflow Sorry, I edited the answer - you need to escape the `{` and `}` invscode.

Comment: Within vscode, that seems to just select everything?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did, it literally selects every line.